How can I make an image fit the width and height of a div in HTML and CSS?
I have a container with the width of 100%. I then added left div of 40% and right div of 60% to make it 100% width. I added an image to the right div and wanted it to fit the width and height of the div but instead it covers half of the right width but fit the hight.
In my CSS, i make the width and the height to be 100% to make sure it covers the whole width and height. i also added object-fit:cover but still did n0t work. please help.


.right-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.right-section .dashboard-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
<div class="right-section">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600" alt="Dashboard Image" class="dashboard-image" />
  <div class="info-box">
    <h2>Customer Management</h2>
    <p>Manage all customers from individual customers to corporate or group customers.</p>
  </div>
</div>




here's the HTML and CSS code: 


Customer Management
Manage all customers from individual customers to corporate or group
customers.
 

Below is the CSS: Here is the CSS
.right-section {
position: relative;
width: 60%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
border: 2px solid green;
}
.right-section .dashboard-image {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
z-index: -1;
}

I added a placeholder image and the issue is not reproducible, the image already covers all of the div, can you try with your real image?

I added .container to help with showing an answer.
The height on .container is arbitrarily set to 75vh for demonstration purposes
"display: flex" on .info-box to allow centering (presuming you would like that)
"position: absolute" on .info-box so it allows the image as a background
This code seems to be working for me:


.container {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 75vh;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
.left-section {
    display: flex;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    }
    
.right-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.right-section .dashboard-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
    .info-box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        align-self: center;
    }
<div class="container">
 <div class="left-section">
     
 </div>

 <div class="right-section">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600" alt="Dashboard Image" class="dashboard-image" />
  <div class="info-box">
    <h2>Customer Management</h2>
    <p>Manage all customers from individual customers to corporate or group customers.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>



